# WKWebView callback without WKScriptMessage

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, webkit, wkwebview

There does not seem to be much information out there on using `WKWebView` with objective-c on macOS so I have been trying to make due using various iOS/Swift examples.  The problem is that my callback from JS to ObjC does not work.  Even the breakpoint set at the `userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message` function is never hit.

Clearly I am missing a step here.

My AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <WKScriptMessageHandler>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController
      didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
    NSLog(@"callback");
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [WKWebViewConfiguration alloc];
    [[config userContentController] addScriptMessageHandler:self name: @"log"];
    WKWebView *webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[_window contentView] frame] configuration:config];
    NSString *htmlStr = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"myFunction()\">Click Me!</button><script     type=\"text/javascript\">function myFunction() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.log.postMessage();}</script></body></html>";
    [[_window contentView] addSubview:webview];
    [webview loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue yet? I am facing this issue currently

Comment: @John I did end up figuring this out. Just forgot to post the answer.

Comment: I managed to find other solution, but thank anyways =) Hope it could benefit others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the original code does not work is twofold. First is simply because `WKWebviewConfiguration` needs to be initialized by itself (WKWebView does not initialize its configuration for you) and second is that `postMessage` must have at least one argument.

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <WKScriptMessageHandler>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController
      didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
    NSLog(@"callback");
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    [[config userContentController] addScriptMessageHandler:self name: @"log"];
    WKWebView *webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[_window contentView] frame] configuration:config];
    NSString *htmlStr = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"myFunction()\">Click Me!</button><script type=\"text/javascript\">function myFunction() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.log.postMessage(null); }</script></body></html>";
    [[_window contentView] addSubview:webview];
    [webview loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
}
```

Here is how you would pass an argument

```
 - (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController
       didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
     if ([message.name isEqualToString:@"log"])
         NSLog(@"%@", message.body);

 }
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    [[config userContentController] addScriptMessageHandler:self name: @"log"];
    WKWebView *webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[_window contentView] frame] configuration:config];
    NSString *htmlStr = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"myFunction()\">Click Me!</button><script type=\"text/javascript\">function myFunction() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.log.postMessage('clicked'); }</script></body></html>";
    [[_window contentView] addSubview:webview];
    [webview loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
}
```